# How to check if a bean is related

Tags: php, mysql, relationship, sugarcrm

I'm fairly new to SugarCRM and I would like to know something about relationships. I have a bean lets say Account and an ID of a record in the database, lets say contact. Now I would like to know if this record is already related to the account.

As far as I could find out is that there are a couple of ways on how to get the result

1. Do a SQL query directly on the database in the related tables
2. Load the relationship from the Account and loop through the beans to see if I can find the bean with the record id provided.

Both seem a bit clumsy to me. I would like to know if there is a better way on how to solve this. I was hopeing there was a 'contains' or 'has' method in the link2 class but unfortunately this wasn't the case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There isn't any way to do this that I know of; but it's possible something exists buried in the Bean Framework.

Typically I work with large datasets and batch processing in SugarCRM, so I just use raw SQL queries for most everything.  They are a lot faster than the Bean Framework (100 to 1000 times faster or more, in my experience), and the query code is easy enough to put in some some simple utility function.

The downside of the raw SQL approach is that every different kind of Bean in SugarCRM can relate to other Beans in different ways.  That is, they don't all use the same convention - e.g. the `accounts_contacts` table handles relationships between Accounts and Contacts, whereas for Quotes there is simply a field in Quotes called `account_id`.

Because of this, you can't just write one SQL-relationship-search utility function and be done with it.  You'd need a separate one for each bean combination that you will be searching.

For me, that's the best option regardless due to efficiency concerns when working with a lot of Beans.

If you're working with batch data, definitely go with the SQL approach even if there is a simple function in the Bean Framework to do the relationship look-up.

It comes down to how efficient and fast you need your code to run.